# Missing Numeric Values Converted to character

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that from one of the variables that had both Numeric and character values.  I had to convert those that has numbers and used them for calculations then return them back to Character so that I could append them back to the characters.  After appending them, some of them had missing value designated as (.) which I want to overwrite using another variable called status that has Yes or No as values.

My challenge now is how to identify those that has . as missing values and get them overwritten with the status.

I have tried

```
proc sql;
create table Track as 
select *,
case when acct in (' ','.') then status
else acct
from Acct_table;
quit;
```

also tried

```
case when acct is null then status
```

but neither of the above seem to be working.

Comment: In `datalines` format, can you give us some sample data that reproduces the issue you are describing?

Comment: Did you look at the Log window ? What messages appeared there ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the period is not in the first character of the string.  If you did

```
acct = put(acct_num,10.);
```

Then the character variable will have 9 spaces and then the period.

If you did:

```
acct = acct_num;
```

Then SAS will do an implicit conversion using the BEST12. format so there will be 11 leading spaces.

So change your test.

```
case when left(acct) in (' ','.') then
```

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this with one of my senior colleague that came back from annual leave and he said is because the location of the point(.) might be a tricky one so the advice that I use compress and it worked 
case when compress(acct) ="." then status 
else acct

Thank you all so much for your contributions